# What's a word for someone who does what they say?

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word that means something like 'being a man/woman of your word', or 'follow through' as a noun. I tried using 'integrity' at first, but that has other implications, like honesty and other moral principles.

Comment: When you ask for a 'word', it helps if you say whether you want a noun, an adjective or a verb. Also a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go is helpful for context.

Comment: Yes, noun or verb should work (adjective would be acceptable, though not as ideal, but how many adjectives can't be nounified?). It's not used for a sentence, unfortunately, it's more for a heading/title type of usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Consistent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consistent)*** may convey the idea:

> - agreeing or accordant; compatible; not self-contradictory: *actions consistent with his views.*

The Free Dictionary

Comment: That is close, but by itself could have connotations of consistency across various aspects of life, or consistency in showing up or something. It might end up being the best fit, however.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe reliable or trustworthy?

Comment: Basically the same comment goes here as for 'consistent'. These words are close enough that they might work, but still have connotations that I'm hoping to exclude

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ***[dependable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dependable)*** conveys what you want?

> Definition of dependable in English:
>   adjective
>
> - Trustworthy and reliable:
>     *'a dependable supply of cold beer'
>
>     'the most valuable and dependable of America’s allies'
>
>     'Growth tends to be mundane with the main attraction being dependable cash flows and reliable dividend payments.'
>
>     'Pierre was the head of all the servants and he was a very reliable and dependable man.'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dependable

Answer (score 1):

If someone can be described as 'credible', I guess you could assume, we can believe what he/she says to be the truth. Going a bit further, maybe we could also assume that when he/she says something will be done by him/her, then that will be done by him/her definitely.

Answer (score 0):

A person who does what they say they will do is a person who honors their commitments and keeps their promises.

So I would describe such a person as **honorable** and **trustworthy**.

If you want to go a bit exotic use **mensch**, which is a [Yiddish term meaning a person of integrity and honor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensch).

> #### mensch
>
> Someone to admire and emulate, someone of noble character. The key to
>   being “a real mensch” is nothing less than character, rectitude,
>   dignity, a sense of what is right, responsible, decorous.
>   ~ *from [How to Be a Mensch](http://guykawasaki.com/how_to_be_a_men/) by Guy Kawasaki*

Answer (score 0):

*True to his word*

(trying tchrist's formatting -- no bold!)