# What is a word or term with an opposite or complementary meaning to "flaky person"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, antonyms

One good candidate would be "reliable", but I am looking for a word with more direct connotations to social behavior like flaky has.

Comment: Is this answered by [What's a word for someone who does what they say?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/270121/191178) (or its duplicate)? If not, how is your question different?

Comment: Hey new user, thanks for an interesting question.  But note that I voted to close because you're supposed to share the efforts you made so far ("your research") to figure this out yourself. / *Reliable.  She's got it together.  He's got his feet on the ground.* There are other ways but we also need to see how you want to use it.

Comment: Asking for a "term with an opposite or complementary meaning" makes no sense: you're asking for both synonyms and antonyms. Please [edit] your post to narrow the question to one or the other, and add a sample sentence to show how the word would be used. For further guidance, see [ask], review the requirements for [tag:single-word-requests] and take our EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I offer **solid** as a complementary word to **flaky**, in a similar register.
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/solid) has:

> **solid**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **4** Dependable; reliable.
> *The real man was solid, dependable, loyal, uncomplaining, quick to act and slow to forgive.*

Answer (score 0):

**down-to-earth** (adj.)

> Practical and sensible [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down-to-earth)

> With no illusions or pretensions; practical and realistic [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/down_to_earth)

---

> Monique could demonstrate to Jenny by her many humanitarian activities
> that she was not heartless, and Jenny could demonstrate to Monique by
> her efficiency and  organizational skills that she was not “**flaky**"
> or insufficiently **down-to-earth**. [Lucille Osterweil;
> *Lifedance*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lifedance/Sc1HVj65Q40C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=down%20to%20earth%20not%20flaky&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover) (2001)